# How to fetch the data in datastore with a key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a problem in fetching the data from the datastore. I have the key for the entity but using that key i am able to fetch the ID, Kind name, but not the properties

here is the code i tried.

```
        for(int j=0;j<mem.size();j++) 
        {
            Key key=mem.get(j);
            Entity con=new Entity(key);

            System.out.println("Kind Name = "+con.getKind() );

            System.out.println("Key = "+con.getKey() );
            System.out.println("ID = "+con.getKey().getId() );
            System.out.println("first name="+con.getProperty("FirstName") );
        }
```

the getproperty() method does not fetch the data

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing a new `Entity` with the given key does not fetch the entity from the datastore, it creates a new entity in memory with the same key.  To get the entity, you must call `datastore.get(key)` (where `datastore` is the `DatastoreService` that you create with `DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService()`).